# Why my viewModel function won't load data from JSON using retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

In my application i'm using Navigation Compose. After implementing it, my viewModel's function getExercises() won't fetch the data. Why is that?

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

lateinit var navController: NavHostController
lateinit var viewModel: ExerciseViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        GymEncV2Theme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme

            navController = rememberNavController()
            viewModel = ExerciseViewModel()

            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                SetupNavGraph(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

NavGraph:

```
@Composable
```

fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController, viewModel: ExerciseViewModel) {

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.Home.route) {

    composable(
        route = Screen.Home.route
    ) {
        HomeScreen(navController = navController)
    }

    composable(
        route = Screen.SampleExercise.route,
        arguments = listOf(navArgument(SAMPLE_EXERCISE_SCREEN_KEY) {
            type = NavType.StringType
        })
    ) {
        SampleExerciseScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel, muscleGroup = it.arguments?.getString(
            SAMPLE_EXERCISE_SCREEN_KEY).toString())
    }

}
```

}

ExerciseApi built with Retrofit:

```
interface ExerciseApi {

@GET("GymEnc_v2.JSON")
suspend fun getExercises() : List<Exercise>

companion object {
    private var exerciseApi: ExerciseApi? = null

    fun getInstance() : ExerciseApi {
        if (exerciseApi == null) {
            exerciseApi = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ExerciseApi::class.java)
        }
        return exerciseApi!!
    }
}
```

}

Repository Implementation:

```
class ExerciseRepositoryImpl : ExerciseRepository {

private val api = ExerciseApi.getInstance()

override suspend fun getExercises(): List<Exercise> {
    return api.getExercises()

}
```

}

And finally the viewModel:

```
class ExerciseViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val repository = ExerciseRepositoryImpl()

var exerciseListResponse : List<Exercise> by mutableStateOf(arrayListOf())
var errorMessage: String by mutableStateOf("")


fun getExercises(): List<Exercise>{
    viewModelScope.launch {

        try {
            val exerciseList = repository.getExercises()
            exerciseListResponse = exerciseList
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            errorMessage = e.message.toString()
        }

    }
    return exerciseListResponse
}
```

}

SampleExercisesScreen:

```
@Composable
```

fun SampleExerciseScreen(navController: NavController, muscleGroup: String, viewModel: ExerciseViewModel) {

```
val exerciseList = viewModel.getExercises().filter { it.muscle == muscleGroup }

Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
color = AppColors.mBackground) {

    Column {

        MyTopBar(navController = navController)

        Text(text = muscleGroup,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
        color = AppColors.mDetails,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center)

        UserExercisesButton()
    }

}
```

}

After using viewModel.getExercises() in SampleExercisesScreen, they simply won't load, leaving me with an empty list.

Comment: Add a `Log.e()` call to your `catch` block in `ExerciseViewModel` `getExercises()` function, and see what exception is getting logged. Or, use a debugger to get the exception information, if you prefer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added Log.e("msg", errorMessage) line if this is what you meant and nothing is getting logged.

Comment: Then you might want to put a breakpoint in `getExercises()` and see if it is getting called. You did not provide `SampleExercisesScreen()`, and perhaps there is an issue there.

Comment: @CommonsWare i've edited the question and provided **SampleExercisesScreen()**.

Comment: @CommonsWare The app crashes when I'm trying to use exerciseList[0], with simple error Index Out Of Range, so the **getExercises()** method fails to fetch the data from JSON.

Comment: Consider adding the OkHttp logging interceptor or Flipper or something, so you can see exactly what JSON you are getting back from your server.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added the OkHttp logging interceptor and all the data seems to be fetching properly. All the data was logged properly, so i don't know why the **exerciseList** still seems empty

Comment: Usually, if there is a major problem with parsing, Gson will throw an exception. But, in general, make sure that `List<Exercise>` really does match the JSON.

Comment: I've found the problem. I had to move declaring **exerciseList** to a higher class, and then pass it to the SampleExerciseScreen as a parameter. Thanks for your help